# 'Array<Element>' is not convertible to 'Array<Int>'

Tags: swift, generics, functional-programming, lazy-sequences

I can create an iterator to create prefixes:

```
extension Array where Element == Int {
  func prefixesInt() -> AnyIterator<[Element]> {
    var length = 0
    return AnyIterator {
      guard length < self.count else { return nil }
      length += 1
      return Array(self.prefix(length))
    }
  }
}

for prefix in [1,10,5].prefixesInt() {
  print(prefix)  // Prints: [1]  then  [1, 10]  then [1, 10, 5]
}
```

Now I want to achieve the same with other types by:

1) Encoding the types to Ints

2) Using the same prefix function

3) Decoding back to the original type

[I know there might be other ways to achieve this but I want to follow this line for various reasons and also wanting to understand more.]

So I need:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
  func encode() -> [Int] {
    return map { self.firstIndex(of: $0)! }
  }
}
print(["A", "B", "A", "C"].encode())  // Prints: [0, 1, 0, 3]

extension Array where Element == Int {
  func decode<Output>(_ original: [Output]) -> [Output] {
    return map { original[$0] }
  }
}
print([2,3,0].decode(["P", "Q", "R", "S"]))  // Prints: ["R", "S", "P"]
```

I can now do what I want with:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
  func prefixes() -> LazyMapSequence<AnyIterator<[Int]>, [Element]> {
    return encode().prefixesInt().lazy.map { $0.decode(self) }
  }
}

for prefix in ["H","A","T"].prefixes() {
  print(prefix)
}
```

I now want to go a step further by making the transform (in this case prefixes) into a parameter and my attempt is:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
  func encodeTransformDecode(transform: ([Int]) -> AnyIterator<[Int]> ) -> LazyMapSequence<AnyIterator<[Int]>, [Element]> {
    return transform(encode()).lazy.map { $0.decode(self) }
  }
}
```

which compiles fine but when I try:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
  func prefixes2() -> LazyMapSequence<AnyIterator<[Element]>, [Element]> {
    return encodeTransformDecode(transform: prefixesInt) //ERROR: 'Array<Element>' is not convertible to 'Array<Int>'
  }
}

for prefix in ["A","B","C"].prefixes2() {
  print(prefix)
}
```

Then I get the error indicated

I'm stuck.  Any help appreciated.

Whole code:

```
print("========== prefixesInt")
extension Array where Element == Int {
  func prefixesInt() -> AnyIterator<[Element]> {
    var length = 0
    return AnyIterator {
      guard length < self.count else { return nil }
      length += 1
      return Array(self.prefix(length))
    }
  }
}

for prefix in [1,10,5].prefixesInt() {
  print(prefix)  // Prints: [1]  then  [1, 10]  then [1, 10, 5]
}

print("============ encode")
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
  func encode() -> [Int] {
    return map { self.firstIndex(of: $0)! }
  }
}
print(["A", "B", "A", "C"].encode())  // Prints: [0, 1, 0, 3]

print("============ decode")
extension Array where Element == Int {
  func decode<Output>(_ original: [Output]) -> [Output] {
    return map { original[$0] }
  }
}
print([2,3,0].decode(["P", "Q", "R", "S"]))  // Prints: ["R", "S", "P"]

print("============ prefixes")
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
  func prefixes() -> LazyMapSequence<AnyIterator<[Int]>, [Element]> {
    return encode().prefixesInt().lazy.map { $0.decode(self) }
  }
}

for prefix in ["H","A","T"].prefixes() {
  print(prefix)
}

extension Array where Element: Equatable {
  func encodeTransformDecode(transform: ([Int]) -> AnyIterator<[Int]> ) -> LazyMapSequence<AnyIterator<[Int]>, [Element]> {
    return transform(encode()).lazy.map { $0.decode(self) }
  }
}

print("============ prefixes2")
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
  func prefixes2() -> LazyMapSequence<AnyIterator<[Element]>, [Element]> {
    return encodeTransformDecode(transform: prefixesInt)
  }
}

for prefix in ["A","B","C"].prefixes2() {
  print(prefix)
}
```

Comment: `prefixesInt` is only defined on `Array where Element == Int` and not arrays in general

Comment: But encodeTransformDecode's signature is asking that transform has type: ([Int]) -> AnyIterator<[Int]> so not clear on the message?

Comment: You can't call `prefixesInt` from an array where the only constraint on element is to be equatable. Plus the signature of `prefixesInt` is not `([Int]) -> AnyIterator<[Int]>`

Comment: What version of Xcode/Swift are you using? Commenting out your error at the end and running produces output at expected plus `SWIFT RUNTIME BUG: unable to demangle type of field '_transform'. mangled type name is 'q_7ElementSTQzc'` in Xcode 10.0/Swift 4.2 playground

Comment: Hi @CRD, Version is Xcode 10.1 (10B61)

Comment: Thanks @Carpsen90 for your help with this. Your question makes me realise I'm not clear on the type of prefixesInt.  I assumed because it was a method on `[Int]` and returns `AnyIterator<[Int]>`, that it's type would be  `([Int]) -> AnyIterator<[Int]>` but I guess I'm not right?

Comment: Its type is `() -> AnyIterator<[Int]>`.

Comment: I think one thing you are missing is that in `encodeTransformDecode(transform: prefixesInt)` there is an *implicit* `self` reference as `prefixesInt` is an instance method – and in this case that `self` is not of type `[Int]`. This gives you two problems, wrong type, and even if it was the right type you've implicitly bound the `self`. If you define a `static` `prefixesInt` method which takes an `[Int]` and simply calls the instance version on its arg, pass that to `encodeTransformDecode`, you'll get further. (I've got your code "working" in 10.0 but its spewing RUNTIME BUGs so won't post!)

Comment: Thanks @CRD.  I had wondered about that but wasn't very clear on it so your comment nudged me to explore...
I was very keen not to go the static route - it makes other parts of the code less elegant.
I had a rather vague memory of some currying methods from the excellent "obj Functional Swift".
So I looked it up and it helped me clarify that the type of `prefixesInt` is in fact: `(Array<Int>) -> () -> AnyIterator<[Int]>`.
Realising that gives me a solution.
I'll post my findings as an Answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As indicated in my comment and you've explored in your own answer, the core problem in your code is that you had the type of `prefixesInt` incorrect. An instance method has a type of the form:

```
(<object type>) -> (<argument types>) -> <return type>
```

the value passed for `<object type>` is what is bound to `self` in the function. So the type `prefixesInt` is:

```
([Int]) -> () -> AnyIterator<[Int]>
```

To fix your code you only need to change `prefixes2`:

```
func prefixes2() -> LazyMapSequence<AnyIterator<[Int]>, [Element]>
{
   return encodeTransformDecode(transform: { $0.prefixesInt() } )
}
```

The type has changed to include `AnyIterator<[Int]>` rather than `AnyIterator<[Element]>` and a closure `{ $0.prefixesInt() }` is passed rather than just `prefixesInt` (The former takes the array as argument while the compiler passes the latter, which is a shorthand for `self.prefixesInt`, as a closure with the current value of `self` pre-bound – that `self` being the `Array<Equatable>` `prefixes2` was called on).

HTH

---

To see the connection with the code you produced consider that:

```
<value>.method(<args>)
```

is just a shorthand for:

```
<type of value>.method(<value>)(<args>)
```

Which in this case means that:

```
$0.prefixesInt()
```

is a shorthand for:

```
Array<Int>.prefixesInt($0)()
```

which is what you produced but distributed between `prefixes()` (`Array<Int>.prefixesInt`) and `encodeTransformDecode` (`transform(encode())()`). By using the shorthand and passing the closure no changes to `encodeTransformDecode` are required.

Comment: Thanks CRD.  Your answer really clarifies my understanding further.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

With the help of useful nudges from @Carpsen90 and @CRD (thanks both!) and some dipping into the excellent book "obj Functional Swift" (No personal connection) I worked out a solution.

The type of an instance method is different from a static method as shown by:

```
extension Int {
  static func doubleStatic(_ x: Int) -> Int { return x * 2 }
  func doubleInstance() -> Int { return self * 2 }
}
print( type(of: Int.doubleStatic) )    // Prints: (Int) -> Int
print( type(of: Int.doubleInstance) )  // Prints: (Int) -> () -> Int
```

In the question the type of `prefixesInt` is in fact: `(Array<Int>) -> () -> AnyIterator<[Int]>`.
With this in mind we can rewrite `encodeTransformDecode` as follows:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
  func encodeTransformDecode(transform: (Array<Int>) -> () -> AnyIterator<[Int]> ) -> LazyMapSequence<AnyIterator<[Int]>, [Element]> {
    return transform(encode())().lazy.map { $0.decode(self) }
  }
}
```

Secondly we need to tell the Compiler a bit more about the type of `prefixesInt` when we use it in `prefixes2` so:

```
extension Array where Element: Equatable {
  func prefixes2() -> LazyMapSequence<AnyIterator<[Int]>, [Element]> {
    return encodeTransformDecode(transform: Array<Int>.prefixesInt)
  }
}
```

and now as required:

```
for prefix in ["A","B","C"].prefixes2() {
  print(prefix)
}
```

gives us:

```
["A"]
["A", "B"]
["A", "B", "C"]
```

and now very easily we can extend with other function very succinctly:

```
extension Array where Element == Int {
  func suffixesInt() -> AnyIterator<[Element]> {
    var length = 0
    return AnyIterator {
      guard length < self.count else { return nil }
      length += 1
      return Array(self.suffix(length))
    }
  }
}

extension Array where Element: Equatable {
  func suffixes2() -> LazyMapSequence<AnyIterator<[Int]>, [Element]> {
    return encodeTransformDecode(transform: Array<Int>.suffixesInt)
  }
}

for suffix in ["A","B","C"].suffixes2() {
  print(suffix)
}
```

Comment: Arguably the phrase: `transform(encode())().lazy.map { $0.decode(self) }` is cryptic and might be better as: 
`let encoded = encode()` 
`let transformFunction = transform(encoded)`   
`let transformIterator = transformFunction()`  
`let lazyTransformIterator = transformIterator.lazy`   
`return lazyTransformIterator.map { $0.decode(self) }`